# Error with Spring Data JPA nativeQuery String search

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hibernate-native-query

please help.
When I input searchString = "abc" then it works.
But when I input searchString = "a", then it shows the followed error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'q' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2297) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2843) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2825) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2657) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2141) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1169) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.count(JpaQueryExecution.java:183) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.lambda$doExecute$0(JpaQueryExecution.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.support.PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(PageableExecutionUtils.java:62) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(PageableExecutionUtils.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:177) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy131.test(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.hcmute.tlcn2021.service.impl.QuestionServiceImpl.findAll(QuestionServiceImpl.java:76) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.hcmute.tlcn2021.service.impl.QuestionServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8db6b79b.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at com.hcmute.tlcn2021.service.impl.QuestionServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88a3b042.findAll(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.hcmute.tlcn2021.controller.QuestionController.findAll(QuestionController.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.hcmute.tlcn2021.controller.QuestionController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f1a36b3.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at com.hcmute.tlcn2021.controller.QuestionController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$80024b26.findAll(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    ...
```

Here is my Repository code:

```
@Repository
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, Long> {

    ...
    @Query(value = " SELECT q.* " +
            " FROM question q " +
            " WHERE q.is_private = FALSE " +
            " AND (UPPER(q.title) LIKE :searchString OR UPPER(q.content) LIKE :searchString OR UPPER(q.answer) LIKE :searchString) ", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Question> test(@Param("searchString") String searchString, Pageable pageable);

    ...

}
```

And here is code in the service:

```
  @Override
    public PaginationResponse findAll(Long facultyId, String searchString, Pageable pageable) {

        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(searchString)) searchString = "";
        searchString = "%" + searchString.toUpperCase() + "%";

        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(facultyId) || facultyId == 0) {
            Page<Question> queryResult =questionRepository.test(searchString, pageable);
            return convert(queryResult);
        }
        return convert(questionRepository.findAllByFaculty_IdEqualsAndIsPrivateFalseAndAnswerNotNull(facultyId, searchString, pageable));
    }
```

I debugged and it didn't go through with the questionRepository.test(...) method when I give searchString= "a".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I should have use JPQL instead of nativeQuery. It works fine with JPQL now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).